# How to get values from ModelForm

Tags: python, django

How to show captured data in ModelForm, **quantity** in this example, how to show it in template and how to get it in database

models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):

    PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = (
        (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)
    )

    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=2, choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES)
    order_no = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, )
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, )
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.product, self.quantity)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('product',)  # This defines how we can order products


class CartAddProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ['quantity']
```

views.py

```
def add_to_cart(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
        if form.is_valid():
            quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            quantity.save()

            order_item, status = 
                 OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(product=product)
            user_order, status = 
                 Order.objects.get_or_create(owner=user_profile)
            user_order.items.add(order_item) 
            print (quantity)

        context = {'form': form, 'quantity': quantity, }
        return render(request, 'cart/cart_details.html', context)
```

All these formats but none of them works !!

Comment: So what is your question. You get the quantity. Why can't you send it to a template?

Comment: Hey Daniel, exactly I can get it in server outputs and in /cart/add/<id>/ page but cannot get it here. I added the template code to show it.

Comment: How are you sending that back to the template? Show the rest of the view.

Comment: template.html
    `{% block content %}
        Requested Products:<br>
        {% for item in order.get_cart_items %}
   
            {{ item.product.name }} |
            {{ item.product.quantity }}
            {{ quantity }}
        {% endfor %}
    
            {{ quantity }}
            {{ product.quantity }}
    {% endblock %}`

Comment: I updated the entire view function above.